# Position a DIV inside another DIV to the bottom

Tags: css, html, css-position

I'm trying to position a DIV inside another DIV on its' bottom part.

When I set the outer divs' height to some absolute height (i.e - 100px), it works fine. When It's set to percents or isn't set at all - I can't position it.

Here is my CSS:

```
#left_pane 
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 21px;
    position: relative;
}

#bottom_pic_wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

the `#bottom_pic_wrapper` is inside of `#left_pane` and should be aligned to its' bottom.

Any ideas why this won't work for me?

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think you can set something as a % unless the parent element has a height

Comment: i made a simple example , let me know if your requirements are different , change your height , but it always stays at the bottom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made one example here in jsfiddle , see if it useful to you

http://jsfiddle.net/RJXez/

let me know if you need anything else

The following code should help you position at the bottom always

```
var parentOffset = $('#div').offset();
   var parentsHeight= $('#div').height();
   var childsTopPostion= (parentOffset.top+parentsHeight) - heightOfchildDiv

   $('#childdiv').css('top',childsTopPostion);
   $('#childdiv').css('left',parentOffset.left);
```

Comment: Many thanks - but the problem is I don't know what is the height of left_pane will be (it's dynamic).

Comment: roaman , got it , can you look at this article once , http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html , meanwhile i will comeup with someother solution

Comment: @roman , i got a idea, use juery's offset and always position relative to the parent at the bottom , howz this idea?? are you familier with jquery offset or do you need some example , get offset , calculate your div height using jquery and then add that height to the top propery and set the div postion, this should work.

Comment: @roman , try it , let me know if you need any help , i think we can achieve this

Comment: @gov - Thank you very very much. Sadly - jQuery also can't get the height of a dynamically changed height.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example code to align vertically bottom inside a div

http://www.templatespoint.com/blog/2009/06/div-valign-bottom/